# Is there any advantage in terms of speed by using MIN MAX instead of checking the range by regular code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see this code segment on a sample application created by Apple:

```
- (AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains)normalizedGains:(AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains)gains
{
    AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains g = gains;

    g.redGain = MAX( 1.0, g.redGain );
    g.greenGain = MAX( 1.0, g.greenGain );
    g.blueGain = MAX( 1.0, g.blueGain );

    g.redGain = MIN( self.videoDevice.maxWhiteBalanceGain, g.redGain );
    g.greenGain = MIN( self.videoDevice.maxWhiteBalanceGain, g.greenGain );
    g.blueGain = MIN( self.videoDevice.maxWhiteBalanceGain, g.blueGain );

    return g;
}
```

Apple is checking red, green and blue gain values to prevent values from lying outside a valid range.

OK, I know what MIN MAX do, but is that really necessary to write this like they did? This kind of code makes your brain burn for a micro-second because it is hard to understand that at a glance if you never saw that before.

Instead wouldn't easier to write a function to check that? Like:

```
- (CGFloat) checkValue:(CGFloat)v againstMinimum:(CGFloat)min andMaximum:(CGFloat)max {
  if (v < min) return min;
  if (v > max) return max; 
  return v;
}
```

Or write a static block inside the function, if they did not want the code to grow outside the function.

My question is: is there any gain in speed by using one method or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: is there any gain in speed by using one method or the other?

Well `MIN` and `MAX` are macros which expand to inline code, while your `checkValue:againstMinimum:andMaximum:` is a method which will require a method dispatch – so the former is undoubtedly faster, but the benefit is probably insignificant over the whole application.

If you want clarity, and you should, but not pay too much for it you could start with a function:

```
CGFloat checkValue(CGFloat min, CGFloat v, CGFloat max)
{
   if (v < min) return min;
   if (v > max) return max; 
   return v;
}
```

and to get the benefit of inlining add `NS_INLINE`:

```
NS_INLINE CGFloat checkValue(CGFloat min, CGFloat v, CGFloat max) ...
```

Both of those have the advantage they are functions – typically better compiler error messages, no strange effects from double-evaluation of arguments, etc. – but if you like macro solutions you can just go with:

```
#define CLAMP(lower, v, upper) MIN(MAX(lower, v), upper)
```

Pick which you find *clearest*, don't concern yourself too much over the *speed* – unless later analysis shows it to be an issue.

HTH

Comment: You have used `NS_INLINE` instead of just using `inline`... why is that?

Comment: Look up the definition of `NS_INLINE` and you'll see it expands to both an inlining attribute and `static`, which stops the function name being added to the global namespace. It is just a convenient macro defined by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

`MIN` and `MAX` are macros that expand -- at the start of compilation -- to roughly `(a < b)? a : b` for MIN and the opposite for MAX.  Not considering detailed differences between the conditional `if` and the ternary `?`, they are all the same.

That is, for all intents and purposes:

```
int a = MAX(b,c);
int a = (b > c)? b : c;
if (b > c) a = b; else a = c;
```

are all the same.

The formulation they chose is really nice, once you get used to seeing it.  It's the idea of "clamping" a value to a range: "These values may come in any which way, but when we're done, they will fall in some range (that's quickly readable in the code as the other params of MIN and MAX)". When I see code like that, it makes me feel comfortable that I'll better understand the math that follows, since I need only consider the clamped range.

I would have called the method "clampedGains" rather than "normalizedGains" gain.  Normalized maps a value into the range 0.0...1.0 by dividing that value by it's theoretical maximum.

Comment: If the binary compiled code is the same, the intention is to make it complex. 